# Dense rank is not generating rows correctly

Tags: sql, date, select, window-functions

I have a table A:

```
Create table A(
    Name varchar(10),
    Number integer,
    Exc integer,
    D1 date
)
```

I have inserted 11 rows.

```
Sel * from A;
```

```
+ -----+--------+-----+------------+
| NAME | NUMBER | EXC | D1         |
+ -----+--------+-----+------------+
| a    |      1 |   1 | 2020-02-03 |
| a    |      1 |   2 | 2020-02-03 |
| a    |      1 |   3 | 2020-02-03 |
| a    |      1 |   4 | 2020-02-03 |
| a    |      1 |   1 | 2020-02-04 |
| a    |      1 |   2 | 2020-02-04 |
| a    |      1 |   3 | 2020-02-04 |
| a    |      1 |   1 | 2020-02-05 |
| a    |      1 |   2 | 2020-02-05 |
| a    |      1 |   3 | 2020-02-05 |
| a    |      1 |   4 | 2020-02-05 |
+ -----+--------+-----+------------+
```

Now, when I apply dense rank like below:

```
sel vt.*,dense_rank() OVER(PARTITION BY Name,Number,EXC ORDER BY D1 ) AS rn
from vt;
```

Output:

```
+ -----+--------+-----+------------+----+
| NAME | NUMBER | EXC | D1         | RN |
+ -----+--------+-----+------------+----+
| a    |      1 |   1 | 2020-02-03 |  1 |
| a    |      1 |   2 | 2020-02-03 |  1 |
| a    |      1 |   3 | 2020-02-03 |  1 |
| a    |      1 |   4 | 2020-02-03 |  1 |
| a    |      1 |   1 | 2020-02-04 |  2 |
| a    |      1 |   2 | 2020-02-04 |  2 |
| a    |      1 |   3 | 2020-02-04 |  2 |
| a    |      1 |   1 | 2020-02-05 |  3 |
| a    |      1 |   2 | 2020-02-05 |  3 |
| a    |      1 |   3 | 2020-02-05 |  3 |
| a    |      1 |   4 | 2020-02-05 |  2 |
+ -----+--------+-----+------------+----+
```

Expected:

```
+ -----+--------+-----+------------+----+
| NAME | NUMBER | EXC | D1         | RN |
+ -----+--------+-----+------------+----+
| a    |      1 |   1 | 2020-02-03 |  1 |
| a    |      1 |   2 | 2020-02-03 |  1 |
| a    |      1 |   3 | 2020-02-03 |  1 |
| a    |      1 |   4 | 2020-02-03 |  1 |
| a    |      1 |   1 | 2020-02-04 |  2 |
| a    |      1 |   2 | 2020-02-04 |  2 |
| a    |      1 |   3 | 2020-02-04 |  2 |
| a    |      1 |   1 | 2020-02-05 |  3 |
| a    |      1 |   2 | 2020-02-05 |  3 |
| a    |      1 |   3 | 2020-02-05 |  3 |
| a    |      1 |   4 | 2020-02-05 |  3 | <-- Difference here
+ -----+--------+-----+------------+----+
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: This is the *second* lowest date for `NAME=a, NUMBER=1, EXC=4`, so why do you expect 3 instead of 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing column `EXC` from the `PARTITION` would give you the results that you expect:

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Name, Number ORDER BY D1)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=167b41ead7700ee10b06ba92bc646db9)**:

```
name | number | exc | d1         | rn
:--- | -----: | --: | :--------- | :-
a    |      1 |   1 | 2020-02-03 | 1 
a    |      1 |   2 | 2020-02-03 | 1 
a    |      1 |   3 | 2020-02-03 | 1 
a    |      1 |   4 | 2020-02-03 | 1 
a    |      1 |   1 | 2020-02-04 | 2 
a    |      1 |   2 | 2020-02-04 | 2 
a    |      1 |   3 | 2020-02-04 | 2 
a    |      1 |   1 | 2020-02-05 | 3 
a    |      1 |   2 | 2020-02-05 | 3 
a    |      1 |   3 | 2020-02-05 | 3 
a    |      1 |   4 | 2020-02-05 | 3
```

Comment: Okay, got it. But can you explain why the rank again reshifted to 2 even the date remains same?

Comment: @Princy: rows that ahve the same name, number and date get the same rank. It increases when the date changes, and resets when name/number are different.

Answer (score 0):

Do you simply want to rank all rows by date? Then remove the partition clause, so the ranking is done not inside groups.

```
select name, number, exc, d1, dense_rank() over (order by d1) as rn
from vt
order by d1, name, number, exc;
```